# Using stored procedure and JRdatasource

Tags: spring-mvc, jasper-reports

Is it possible to use StoredProcedure as well as a *JRdatasource* (*JRBeanCollectionDataSource*) in a single report with subreport?

Stored Proc. is used up in main report and *JR* datasource will be used in *subreport*.

Using Spring MVC

Comment: I've done this before using SubReport elements and Table elements that point to different Data Sources and SQL Connections. 

What are you trying for your SubReport Expression?

Answer (score 1):

Yes , it is possible. You can pass the Bean collection in the subreport as like a variable.

And then for procedure call in main report, 
there are 2 possibilities:

```
1. If your procedure returns some thing and if you would like to use in
the report, then you have to create a function, type and type table
(for holding the result set) for calling the procedure.

2. If the procedure does some DML operation, then you can call directly (without a function)
```